# Is there a way to configure MATLAB's plotchar function to other sizes?

Tags: matlab

`plotchar` plots a 35 element vector as a 5x7 grid.

Is there a way to plot other grid sizes characteres?

Comment: This question should be asked here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38040/matlab

Comment: The site is still inactive, but you can choose to commit to it

Comment: I'm confused as to why the close votes. It comes across as "In order for your question to be answered you *must* commit to a different site." Which comes across as controlling and bullying. (It would be fine if it was "ask it elsewhere", but because it is "commit" then we are in a different ball-park...)